# How can I make my div to remain fixed and no longer change position?

Tags: html, css

At this site there is a slider content. If you change tabs to see that a gray background moves below.

I want to remain fixed.

This is very discreet and you have to look carefully to see.

I put a picture to understand better.

http://i60.tinypic.com/2ef8buq.jpg

This is code CSS:

```
.page-id-1637 #top_footer{width:100%;height:531px;background:#EEEEEE;}
```

This is site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/functionmentes/

How can i solve this problem?

can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the element with the class `.dnd-tabs-wrapper` your javascript for the slider defines `style="height: auto";` causing it to bounce when the height readjusts.

By default the height of the element is 192px you can solve it by just adding

`height: 192px !important` to the rule for `.dnd-tabs-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you change tabs, the height of the div called `dnd-tabs-wrapper` is being changed through javascript. Since this div is above the `.page-id-1637 #top_footer div`, it appears to bounce while the height is changing.

You'll need to stop the height from being changed in your javascript. You won't be able to override this with just CSS (unless you use !important).